# If sets can't contain classes, and all sets are classes, how can sets contain sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I am referring to the notion that a set is a collection of its elements bound to a variable and is therefore a class.

If sets can't contain classes, how is a power set allowed to contain sets that are classes?

I'm reading Set Theory by Zaring and my understanding is that a class is a bound set and therefore the class can't be bound to the set that the class contains, in order to prevent Russell's paradox.

So if a set is a class where it binds it's elements, how is a set able to bind more bound elements if that type of thing is forbidden?

Does this mean Zaring is wrong when declaring that all sets are classes, or am I misunderstanding, and that sets can be turned into classes at will? If the second, does this mean when a set is contained in a set, that the nested set cannot be turned into a class by binding it's variables and adding that bound to the original set?

I ask because in chapter 5 terms are being bound and then those bounds are being bound with other terms, and I am assuming this means that the outer bound must be bound to a class, but I don't understand why the inner bound terms are allowed to be bound to the outer bound. If this is allowed, how is Russell's paradox actually being prevented?

Comment: Sets can't contain **proper** classes. A proper class is any class that is not a set.

Comment: What does "a class is a bound set" mean? At a glance that seems very false - if anything it's the other way around.

Comment: The notation a={x|x€a}. I assumed this meant all the elements are mapped to a bound that is in the class. It does seem better to describe it as a bound set is a class.

Comment: What is bothering me is that all sets are described as being bound sets yet are allowed to contain themselves. I thought this was forbidden to prevent Russell's paradox.

Comment: Perhaps another point of confusion is the definition of **set**. How do you interpret it? Usually the notion of **set** is left undetermined in set theory, and simply means any object in the domain of discourse (i.e. an element of a model of set theory)

Comment: Frequently when you use the set comprehension notation, $\{x\mid\ldots\},$ **none** of the symbols you see between the brackets is a bound, a member of the set, or contained in the set. Instead you get instructions for how to find things that **are** in the set.

Comment: So it seems to me you have multiple misunderstandings, starting with the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding a={x|x€a}? I assumed this meant all the elements in a class are mapped to a bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between *classes* and *proper classes*: every proper class is a class, but the converse is not true. Indeed, "proper class" *means* "class which is not a set," and some (but not all) classes are sets.

The point is that *some* classes can be elements of sets - namely, exactly those classes which happen to be sets themselves. Or, the classes which can*not* be contained in a set are exactly the proper classes.

- In fact, since elements of classes are always sets, the following are equivalent for a class $C$: $C$ is a set (= not a proper class), $C$ is an element of some set, $C$ is an element of some class.

Comment: @AlGJohnston Yes, that's the definition of "proper class" (per the first half of the second sentence of my answer).

Answer (score 1):

- A class is a name for a collection of objects that satisfy some property, where the domain of discourse is all the elements of a *model of set theory*.
- A set is any single element of the domain of discourse, i.e. of a *model of set theory*.
- A proper class is any class that is not a set. That is, a proper class is a collection of objects that are not provably an element of a *model of set theory*.

Every set is a class, since we can define a set $a$ as the class $\{x\mid x\in a\}$.

It is indeed the case that no set can contains proper classes, simply because if a proper class were an element of a set, it would also have to be contained in the model (otherwise we can't express that the class is an element of the set).

---

Of course, this needs some more clarification on *models of set theory*. Let's say that we are interested in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ set theory, then there are certain classes that can be proved to be part of any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

For example, every model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has some element $\varnothing$ that satisfies the property $\forall x(x\in\varnothing\leftrightarrow x\neq x)$, thus it is provable that the empty class $\{x\mid x\neq x\}$ is a *set* in every model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Similarly $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that the union of a set of sets is a set, that the image of a set over any function is a set, etc. Presumably you've seen these kind of results before.

Some other classes are provably never an element of a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. For example, if Russell's class $R=\{ x\mid x\notin x\}$ were a set in some model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in this model both $R\in R$ and $R\notin R$ are true, but a model cannot make contradictory statements true. Thus there is no model of which $R$ could have been an element in the first place. Therefore, in any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we see that $R$ is not a set.

Finally, there are classes that are *sometimes* sets, and *sometimes* proper classes. This depends on which model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ you look at. For example, it is consistent (under strong enough assumptions) with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there exist *inaccessible cardinals* (i.e. there are *sets* that have the property of being an [inaccessible cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal)), but it is also consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there do not exist *inaccessible cardinals*. In a model of the former, the class

$$\{x\mid\exists\kappa(\text{"$\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal" + $|x|\geq \kappa$)}\}$$

is a proper class, since there exists such $\kappa$ and thus this class contains sets of arbitrarily large cardinality. But the same class is equal to the empty *set* in a model of the latter, since in that model there exist no such $\kappa$.